# VueJS + Axios Post request not passing parameter value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, axios

I have a API that updates data in the database but then returns back a query. The API takes a single parameter and it works when testing it manually through browser and when also testing using a axios get request. However for security purposes I wanted to try and stick with POST request and to just test it out, however if I try to run this via a POST (change axios.get to axios.post) request the parameter value is not passed to the API. Here is my axios request below. What could be the issue?

```
                axios.post(window.location.origin + '/API/StateContacts', {
                    params: {
                        STATE_DD_INPUT: stateDD
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.stateContactsArray = response.data;
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response.data.error);
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios `post` second parameter is already the data you are trying to pass. From

```
axios.post(window.location.origin + '/API/StateContacts', {
                    params: {
                        STATE_DD_INPUT: stateDD
                    }
                })
```

to

```
axios.post(window.location.origin + '/API/StateContacts', {
                        STATE_DD_INPUT: stateDD
                    })
```

should solve your issue

## Edit

You commented:

However if I do this and add a `{}` it works but not sure why.

```
axios.post(window.location.origin + '/API/StateContacts', {}, { params: { STATE_DD_INPUT: stateDD } }) .then(response => { this.stateContactsArray = response.data; }).catch(error => { console.log(error.response.data.error); });
```

This is because the [signature](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) for `axios.post` function is:

```
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

Instead of passing the `data` as the second argument you are passing the third argument which is the `config`. The `config` object has the `parameters` key that will add to your request the following query parameters:

```
http://localhost/API/StateContacts?STATE_DD_INPUT=xxx
```

where the query string will be `STATE_DD_INPUT`.

Since we don't know your backend we are assuming that you are using a method to get the query string from the request and not the body of the request. Frameworks like `Laravel` looks at the query string and the body for what you searching. E.g.

```
$request->get('STATE_DD_INPUT')
```

You are probably using a framework that has two different methods. One to get the query parameters (e.g. from the URL - https://localhost/API/StateContacts?STATE_DD_INPUT=xxxx) and other to get from the body (e.g. the one sent in the body request - please, consult this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example) to learn more about POST body). So, maybe somewhere in your backend code you will have

```
$request->body('STATE_DD_INPUT')
```

To be able to get the request from the query string you should have some method to do that. e.g.

```
$request->query('STATE_DD_INPUT')
```

Comment: It does not solve it for some reason. Still not passing parameter. However if I do this and add a {} it works but not sure why. axios.post(window.location.origin + '/API/StateContacts', {}, {
                    params: {
                        STATE_DD_INPUT: stateDD
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.stateContactsArray = response.data;
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response.data.error);
                    });

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 I have updated my question to answer this comment. If this answer answers your question, please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I am going through your answer to fully understand but just for reference I am using asp.net core web api controllers.

Comment: Can you explain what this format is axios.post(url[, data[, config]]) in your post. Adding {} works but I looking at what you posted It is unclear to me this syntax. Is this saying URL contains a data array which contains a config array and my parameters are in the config array which my API must account for and the reason it is working?

Comment: And also in my web API I use FromQuery so why does the parameters in the config work?

Comment: If you send `axios.post(URL, {STATE_DD_INPUT: 1})` it will go in the body of the HTTP request [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST). If you send `axios.post('http://google.com', {}, { params: { STATE_DD_INPUT: 1 } })` you will literally be making the following request: `http://google.com?STATE_DD_INPUT=1`.  One goes in the query parameter (e.g. ?first-parameter=1&second-parameter=2`) and the other goes in the HTTP POST body (e.g. check the docs linked before)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass parameter in header?

```
axios.post(window.location.origin + '/API/StateContacts', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'STATE_DD_INPUT': stateDD
    }
})      
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: any reason to pass it in the header vs something else (assuming body)? Relatively new to http requests so not sure if one is favored over the other.